# How to take a photo inside a While-loop with a webcam in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, webcam-capture

**Situation of the problem:**

The Arduino measures the length of an object. If the length is between a pre-determined interval then the Arduino serial writes a '1' on a particular COM-port. MATLAB will read on the same COM-port so we can read the ‘1’ inside MATLAB. For each '1' (read by Matlab) a photo is taken by a webcam. The following While-loop gives us the opportunity to read the ‘1’ inside MATLAB.

```
clear all
clc

arduino = serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411','BaudRate',9600);

fopen(arduino);
Sensor = true
cam = webcam(2);


while (Sensor) 
    A = fscanf(arduino,'%d')

    if A == 1

        img = snapshot(cam);
        imshow(img);

     end

end

fclose(arduino);
```

But the webcam doesn’t take the picture we want to take.

**We have the following problems:**

The first time that a '1' is read (by Matlab), no photo is taken. The second time there is a photo taken. By the third ‘1’, previous photo changes a bit (but Matlab gives not the photo which is taken by the third ‘1’. Then by the fourth ‘1’, Matlab gives the photo that is taken by the third.

Anybody knows how I can fix this?

Comment: If it does not receive a `1` for the first iteration, what is received instead?

Comment: Nothing is received if it isn't a '1'. MATLAB just has to check if there is a '1'. If there is no '1', MATLAB has to do nothing else but checking for a '1' (fscanf).

Comment: I understand the code, but I want to understand what is happening. Is nothing received the first time, or is something else than a `1` received?

Comment: The first time, the 1 is received but nothing happens. So the webcam doesn't take a picture when the 1 is received by MATLAB.

Comment: So the `A==1` is true and the code is really evaluated?

Comment: yes indeed, that's true.